# что не так с присваиванием значения переменной?

Tags: python

*a* и *b* нормально вводятся, а как дело доходит до *c*, то выдает ошибку "name 'c' is not defined", подскажите ошибочку

```
print(3 if (a := int(input())) == (b := int(input())) == (c := int(input())) else 1 if a != b and a != c else 2)
```

Comment: Python так не работает `cond1 == cond2 == cond3` и любой другой из язык скорее всего работать не будет у Вас не доходит до исполнения код поэтому `c` не определяется. Переписать в одну строку можно, но лично я бы не стал. Кстати во втором случае `if` Вы используете `and`  вот Вам и решение для первого случая, если я правильно понял вашу логику.

Comment: если переписать на `print(3 if (a := int(input())) == (b := int(input())) and a == (c := int(input())) else 1 if a != b and a != c else 2)`  выдаст ту же самую ошибку

Comment: нужно начать с того какие значения Вы вводите, ошибка как я и писал выше в том что до исполнения эта часть не доходит, если до `and` будет `False` то нет смысла смотреть что будет после `and`, опишите в вопросе какую именно задачу Вы хотите решить таким образом простыми словами, я постараюсь помочь.

Comment: И я не понимаю почему Вам настолько принципиально написать все в одну строку, да Python позволяет многие вещи так записывать, но это совсем не означает что нужно всегда писать именно так.

Comment: прекрасно это понимаю, однако данную тему уже изучал и просто  для себя хочу попробовать записать код таким абсурдным и малоуважаемым способом, чтобы лучше понять, как работает язык

Comment: я понял, в чем ошибка, благодарю

Comment: @DaniilLoban, как раз в Питоне `10 == 10 == 10` -> `True`, потому что два сравнения подряд компилятор превращает в `(10 == 10) and (10 == 10)`. Сравните с `a <= x <= b` для проверки что x в диапазоне `[a, b]`.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy задача не в том чтобы оно сравнило числа, а в том чтобы выполнились все `части выражения`, и если Python видит что первая часть не выполнилась ему нет смысла выполнять остальные, и я думаю так во многих языках.

Comment: @DaniilLoban, я хотел сказать что в Питоне это выражение имеет смысл в отличие от, скажем C или Java. Что не имеет смысла, это смешивать побочные эффекты с вычислениями. `:=` - зло.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy солидарен

Answer (score 1):

Я все понял и переписал

```
a, b, c = [int(input()) for i in range(3)]
print(3 if a == b and a == c else 0 if a != b and b != c and a != c else 2)
```

Comment: `a == b and a == c` -> `a == b == c`. Это особенность синтаксиса Питона.

Answer (score 1):

```
print(3 if (a := int(input())) == (b := int(input())) == (c := int(input())) else 1 if a != b and a != c else 2)
```

Если первые два числа различны, то выражение `(c := int(input()))` не вычисляется, число для `c` не вводится, переменная `c` не определяется. При вычислении `a != c` в дальнейшем происходит обращение к неопределённой переменной.

Выражение `A == B == C` в Питоне вычисляется примерно как `(A == B) and (B == C)`. Примерно, потому что `B` вычисляется один раз. В других языках такого нет.

Глядя на вторую запись можно понять что если `A` не равно `B`, то вторая скобка не будет вычислена и соответствующих побочных эффектов не будет. А их тут два: ввод числа из входного потока и определение переменной `c`.

Общая причина почему возникла ошибка - смешение вычислений и побочных эффектов. Всегда нужно быть осторожным. Условный пропуск ввода - катастрофа для пользователя.

Минимальная правка:

```
a = int(input())
b = int(input())
c = int(input())
print(3 if a == b == c else 1 if a != b and a != c else 2)
```

Ориентируясь на другой ответ, можно предложить однострочник:

```
print((None, 3, 2, 0)[len(set(int(input()) for _ in range(3)))])
```